# Vue.js App on Heroku Server: Cannot GET /. How Do I Solve This?

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, heroku, deployment

When I enter my URL for my Vue.js application (https://harrishealthtest.herokuapp.com/), the browser takes me to the homepage. Good. However, when I click on the 'Start' button, that's supposed to take me to '/test', I get this message 'Cannot GET /test'.

What am I doing wrong? I have history mode enabled in my routing. I'm not sure if that is causing issues. Or if it's something to do with the connectivity between my Vue.js app and my Laravel REST API. Both are on separate domains. When I click on 'Start', the app is supposed to take me to '/test', and that's where the data from the API is received.

This is what I currently have in my App.vue file:

```
mounted() {
    fetch('https://pure-mountain-87762.herokuapp.com/', {
    method: 'get'
  })
    .then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  })
    // 'jsonData' refers to the json parsed response
    .then((jsonData) => {
      this.testData = jsonData.data
  })
```

What kind of issue am I having here? Routing? API connectivity? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It seems heroku is pointing to the server instead of the client. I had the same error a few weeks back. Two things:

If you are running two npm commands, resume them in the json file that heroku is pointing at. This is an example:

```
"scripts": {
"client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
"start": "node server.js",
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"client": "npm start --prefix client",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
"heroku-postbuild":
  "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

Add that heroku-postbuild line.
You have to play with the commands in your dev environment, in your computer. Make sure it works in your computer, then push up.
Secondly and this is kinda hacky, however it works for me.

Got to Settings of your app in Heroku, click on Reveal Config Vars button and add this env variable:

```
DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true
```

This helped me. Hope it helps you.

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately, I didn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: If you have managed to deploy it, please post your answer. Otherwise, please update your question with your json file here. If your have server and client, please post both jsons here. thanks.